# GridLayout looks diffrent in Android Studio vs device

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-manifest

I'm new to Android development. Could somebody tell me, why Android Studio [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYdNq.png) is showing different from my phone [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6cAU.png)? What is wrong with the code? Is there any solution to the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.dell.braintrainer.MainActivity">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GO"
            android:id="@+id/btnGO"
            android:textSize="80dp"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:onClick="start"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20s"
            android:id="@+id/timerTextview"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:padding="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0/0"
            android:id="@+id/scoreTextview"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timerTextview"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:padding="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="31 + 12"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scoreTextview"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#050505" />

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
          >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:tag="0"
                android:text="31"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:tag="1"
                android:text="31"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:tag="2"
                android:text="31"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:tag="3"
                android:text="31"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                />
        </GridLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried & clean and rebuild of project & uninstall & reinstall??

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the values for size you are using.

The screen size of your phone and the android studio preview phone are not the same. At least that is what usually happens :P I hope this helps!

Comment: However , finally i realized that we have to used v7 Appcompat Gridlayout , otherwise gridlayout  cannot work with api under 17 ;